# errors when trying to compile android on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: android

here's my error, any help would be greatly appreciated.
libcore/luni/src/main/native/Register.cpp:36: error: undefined reference to 'register_android_system_OsConstants(_JNIEnv*)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [/home/jukie/android/system/out/host/linux-x86/obj32/lib/libjavacore.so] Error 1

system: ubuntu 14.10 building lollipop cm

Comment: I have the same issue. was is resolved ?